# Готовые базы данных в android-приложениях

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Пишу приложение, которое должно работать с БД. Создаю БД через SQLiteStudio, наполняю ее, а как использовать ее - непонятно. В интернете по этому поводу натыкался, в основном, на статьи, рассчитанные на создание пустой БД, в которую пользователь впоследствии добавляет данные и работает с ней. А вот по поводу работы с существующей БД четкого ответа не нашел.

Программированием под Android стал заниматься недавно, поэтому интересует правильный подход к решению этой задачи.

Comment: Вот тут, вроде, есть пара советов: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211290/3212712

Comment: а, вроде, нет...

Comment: Вроде, там как раз описано как в пару строчек открыть БД по кастомному пути вместо дефолтного. Т.е. кладёте БД в `assets` папку и оттуда её открываете.

Comment: Разве не нужно перед этим перенести БД в data\data\*\databases? И разве не существует какого-то стандартного способа решения этой проблемы? Ведь приложений, в которые заложена готовая БД немало и какое-то стандартное решение должно быть

Comment: Так я ж об этом и говорю - кладите вашу готовую БД в папку `путь_к_проекту/папка_проекта/assets` - теперь при сборке `apk` файл БД будет в нём. И вы можете как описано по ссылке выше эту БД открыть. Указанный вами путь - это дефолтный путь к дефолтным БД. Он дефолтный, а не обязательный. В принципе, ничто не мешает вам также и не упаковывать готовую БД в `apk` файл, а открывать её из другого места - с диска, карты памяти `etc` примеры по ссылке говорят о любом пути до файла БД.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, файлы из `assets` доступны только для чтения, т.е. БД так и так придется переносить куда-то, прежде чем работать с ней. Следовательно, возникает необходимость в копировании базы данных в память устройства, притом так, чтобы в случае необходимости была возможность изменить структуру базы данных или наполнить ее данными, т.к. в БД будут содержаться данные, которые идут с приложением и данные, которые туда заносит пользователь.

Comment: Ну, наверное тут вы правы. Тогда да - просто пишите БД из `assets` в дефолтную папку и далее кодом по ссылке её открывайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте библиотеку для открытия БД:

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```

В директории `java` вашего проекта создайте `package`, назовите его например, `DBSetup` в нем создайте класс `DBAssetHelper` наследуемый от `SQLiteAssetHelper`:

```
public class DBAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final int DBVersion = 1;
private static final String DBName = "NameDB";

public DBAssetHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
    }
}
```

Далее в основной директории вашего приложения создайте класс, например `DBSQLiteOpenHelper` наследуемый `SQLiteOpenHelper:`

```
class DBSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DBVersion = 1;
private static final String DBName = "NameDB";
private static final String TableName = "NAME_TABLE";

private static final String mTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TableName +
        "(" + "_id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "CONTENT_ONE" + " TEXT, " + "CONTENT_TWO" + " TEXT)";

DBSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(mTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
    this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Создайте папку `assets`, кликните правой кнопкой по директории `src/new Folder/Assets Folder` в создавшейся папке `assets` создайте директорию `databases` вложите туда файл базы данных, предварительно вырезав `.db`, то есть должно быть `NameDB` вместо `NameDB.db` далее в нужном классе считывайте с него данные:

```
DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(this);
dbSetup.getWritableDatabase();

try{
    SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                "NAME_TABLE", new String[]{"CONTENT_ONE", "CONTENT_TWO"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{Сюда передаем переменную с длиной высоты соответствующей длине нашей БД},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            final String CONTENT_ONE = cursor.getString(0);
            final String CONTENT_TWO = cursor.getString(1);

            TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_one);
            TextView textTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_two);

            textOne.setText(CONTENT_ONE);
            textTwo.setText(CONTENT_TWO);

        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Это самый оптимальный вариант который я смог найти для считывания данных с готовой БД.

Comment: спасибо! работает)

Comment: @mtrfnv если захотите обновлять БД то в классе `DBAssetHelper` в методе `DBAssetHelper` пропишите `setForcedUpgrade(2); предварительно изменив версию БД на 2`