# Обновить существующую базу данных в android-приложении

Tags: android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite, update

Есть приложение, которое работает с базой данных. Процесс создания БД взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708651/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85). В процессе разработки появилась необходимость внести изменения в базу данных, а именно добавить новые записи в таблицу. Записи добавлялись на компьютере, а затем были положены в `*\assets\databases`. Как сделать, чтобы изменения БД отобразились в приложении?

Comment: Спросите @McDaggen - это же его идея была, он посоветовал эту либу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо создать файл `assets/databases/<database_name>_upgrade_<from_version>-<to_version>.sql`, в котором необходимо прописать SQL-команды, производящие изменение текущей БД, в коде увеличить версию БД на 1. Также не обязательно создавать класс `DBSQLiteOpenHelper`, в таком случае в коде можно пользоваться такой конструкцией

```
DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(context);
dbSetup.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBAssetHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```