# Как импортировать готовую базу данных Android?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite, android-fragment

Уже очень долго не могу справится с тем, что задумал, а именно: как включить в проект готовую БД. Перепробовал уже очень много способов,разные библиотеки...но безуспешно. Минут наверное 30 назад, наткнулся на похожий вопрос: [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708651/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

Новичок еще в программировании, пол года как занимаюсь андроид-разработкой и вот-вот столкнулся с базами данных. Сейчас продемонстрирую свою готовую БД и кусочки кода.

[image: Моя база данных]
[image: Древо]

**class DBAssetHelper**

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DBAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final int DBVersion = 1;
private static final String DBName = "accounts";

public DBAssetHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
  }
}
```

**class DatabaseHelper**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DBVersion = 1;
private static final String DBName = "accounts";
private static final String TableName = "accounts";

private static final String mTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TableName +
        "(" + "_id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "CONTENT_ONE" + " TEXT, " + "CONTENT_TWO" + " TEXT)";

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(mTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
    this.onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

**class ListFragment extends Fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(getActivity());
    dbSetup.getWritableDatabase();



    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    //exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp, "1000", "Денежные средства"));
    //exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp, "1010", "Денежные средства в кассе"));

    try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                "accounts", new String[]{"CONTENT_ONE", "CONTENT_TWO"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[3],
                null, null, null);

        do {

            final String CONTENT_ONE = cursor.getString(1);
            final String CONTENT_TWO = cursor.getString(2);

            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp, CONTENT_ONE, CONTENT_TWO));

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    return v;

}
```

Действия происходит во фрагменте, и как я понял, чтобы взять Context, нужно применить метод getActivity().Вроде бы расписал проблему в полной мере. 
должно быть что то вроде этого, вот только этот способ мне не подходит, мне нужно брать информацию из готовой БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572375/8211160. Тут есть развернуто